# Split phone number (mobile or land line) into country code, area code and number

Tags: java, parsing

I need to split a phone number (can be mobile *or* land line) into:

- **country** dialing code
- **area** code
- phone **number**

**Examples:**

> **`+923211234567`** will be **`92 32x 1234567`** (mobile)
>   **`+92992123456`** will be **`92 992 123456`** (land line)

Let's say I have a database with all countries' dialing code, area code, mobile country code, mobile network code...

The problem is that *Country Dialing Code* can be 1, 2 or 3 digits. For example:

> `1` for **USA**, `92` for **Pakistan**, or `233` for **Ghana**

Also, *Area* and *Mobile Network Code* can be 2 or 3 digits. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Phone number parser](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber) library.
A demo page can be found [here](http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/).

Comment: i have seen it but problem is that phoneUtil.parse() requires country code...which i don't have

Comment: It only requires a default country code, let the user input that or choose one that you think will be most common.

Comment: You can pass an empty string for country code In case you haven't it, like phoneUtil.parse("+905555555555", "")

Answer (score 0):

Is that known before splitting whether the number is a Mobile number or a Land line number? If not then even the number can vary in length.

Comment: there is no way to tell that number is mobile or land line...yes its length will be varying you can see example

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
// phone must begin with '+'
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse("your number", "");
int countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();
long nationalNumber = numberProto.getNationalNumber();
Log.i("code", "code " + countryCode);
Log.i("code", "national number " + nationalNumber);
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```